# Chrome and Firefox/IE behaving differently when using negative margins

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having an issue when using a negative top margin. Firefox and IE are rendering it differently from Chrome.

I have a layout similar to the following.

Here is the basic structure of my html

```
<div class="blue">
  <div class="column">Column</div>
  <div class="column">Column</div>
  <div class="column">Column</div>
  <div class="column">Column</div>
</div>
<div class="red">
  <div class="column">Column</div>
  <div class="column">Column</div>
</div>
```

And here is an example image of what I'm trying to do.

[image: Example]

The blue div is a row of columns with a 1px right border. The red div has the slanted image for the background image (transparent png). I'm using a negative margin on the red div to pull it up and cover the very bottom edge of the blue div so that the borders in the blue div touch the slanted area in the red div. (purple area)

My issue is that in Firefox and IE the position of the content in the red div is being pushed down by the amount of negative top margin that I apply to it. In Chrome this issue doesn't exist. For example. If I apply `margin-top: -70px` to the red div it will push the content down 70px in IE/FF as well.

I'm not sure what is going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to show your css as well

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it could be because you didn't post your CSS but maybe you could some [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to reset the default CSS settings. Sometimes you need this because all browsers have different default CSS settings.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers do support different code. Try writing code that is only called if it is in  that browser. Example:

```
    /* Configure the animation for Firefox */
-moz-animation-duration:6s;
-moz-animation-name:spin;
-moz-animation-timing-function:linear;

/* Configure it for Chrome and Safari */
-webkit-animation-duration:6s;
-webkit-animation-name:spin;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
```

This is detecting different browsers and saying different things for each. I used this example because it shows that different code can be used for different browsers and sometimes it is needed. This is on one of my own web apps.